# Use PHP to retrieve information

Tags: php, curl

I am using the following code to retrieve a players account status from minecraft.net.

```
//Checks MC Username For Validation
function checkPlayer($player) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
    die('CURL is not installed!');
}
$ch = curl_init('http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user='.$player.'');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
if (trim($output) == true) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

My host has Curl installed, which I used instead of `file_get_content`, but this doesn't work? Can someone help me please?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: What does `$content` contains?

Comment: `$content` != `$output`

Comment: You will have to be more specific in your question. What exactly didn't work ? I tried to answer the question, but this doesn't work (just kidding :-) ).

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER)`, and then as @onetrickpony says decide on a variable name ....

Comment: @onetrickpony Ok, I didn't know that... I've never used curl before. so I just followed examples online. How would I grab the output of the page, or what is written on the page? Thanks

Comment: **Thanks Guys For Your Help! I got it after reading more on how curl works!**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`.  If you don't, `curl_exec` will echo to the screen instead of returning a string.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your script, fully working.

```
$player = 'PLAYER_NAME';

$url = 'http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=' . $player;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.7) Gecko/20050414 Firefox/1.0.3"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch); 

echo 'RESULT: '. $result;

if ($result === 'true') {
    echo "STATUS OK_OR_WHATEVER";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
} else {
    echo "STATUS FLASE_OR_WHATEVER";
}
```